# Does CountAsync method in EF Core results to SaveChanges or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, savechanges

I have an important question which I couldn't find the answer anywhere!
Suppose we call the Count or CountAsync method in EF or EFCore like this:

```
public async Task<int> Count()
{
    return await _context.Set<TEntity>().CountAsync();
}
```

Does it results to **save or add the entities** into the database **or not**?

Thank you.

Comment: _"Does it results to"_ <-- I don't understand what you're asking. `Count`/`CountAsync` doesn't cause any changes to data, so what "save and add" actions are you referring to?

Comment: "does it take a lot of time to return the response" - only you can quantify what is or is not "a lot of time" and you can best assess this by *running the code* and measuring whether the response time is acceptable for your use case.

Comment: _"And does it take a lot of time to return the response (for big data) or not?"_ - that depends entirely on your database design, network latency, how good your indexes are, database server disk IO speed, etc.

Comment: You could check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.countasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it results to save or add the entities into the database or not?

No. Queries never write to the database. Only SaveChanges writes to the database.

Comment: ...with the exception of a Linq query that represents the result of a `PROCEDURE` though.

Comment: But that would be a raw sql query, not a LINQ query, right?